# Centering variable number of divs inside a div container

Tags: html, css, position

I really need some help as this is driving me nuts!

I need to position x number of child divs (or spans if that helps) inside a parent div. The child divs needs to be centered.

I know the width of the child divs, lets say it's 100px. The width of the parent div is 700px.

Again, the number of child divs can vary from 1 to 7.

The child divs contain an image and a short text.

I've tried to illustrate my desired result in with my insane photoshop skills but being a new user I'm not allowed to upload an image.

Please see my illustration here: http://whiteboxstudio.dk/div%20positioning.jpg

I hope this is sufficient information for you awesome css hackers to help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post here your html code.

Comment: I was sort of hoping that you guys would write up both the html and the css for me as I need to massage it into a bigger scheme. So if you can write me up a super simple example as in the image I've link to you will make my day! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

html

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

this css should work:

```
.parent-div {
    text-align: center;
}

.parent-div div {
    border: green 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
}

.parent-div div:first-of-type {
    border-color: blue;
}

.parent-div div:last-of-type {
    border-color: red;
}
```

to fix inline-block in IE 6/7 for your ie specific stylesheet

```
.parent-div div {
    zoom:1; /* gives layout */
    *display: inline; /* ie6/7 inline */
    _height: 30px; /* ie6 height - height of children */
}
```

Comment: This also works with IE compatibility mode, which was really messing me around. Good job!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? 
HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="padder">
    <span class="blue">
        Blue
    </span>
    <span class="green">
        Green
    </span>
    <span class="red">
        Red
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
   width: 500px;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   text-align: center;
}
#padder{
      margin: 0 auto;
}
.blue{border: 1px solid #0000ff; }
.green{border: 1px solid #00ff00;}
.red{border: 1px solid #ff0000; }
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/LU7Vp/

Answer (score 0):

one way: (but uses inline-block) http://jsfiddle.net/2uKWC/

```
<div id="parent">

    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>

</div>


#parent{
    height:100px;
    border:thin solid yellow;
    text-align:center;
}

.child{
    display:inline-block;
    border:thin solid blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

}
```

Comment: -0: please always separate HTML and CSS.